# opencv FLANN with ORB descriptors?

Tags: c++, opencv, sift, surf

I am trying to use FLANN with ORB descriptors, but opencv crashes with this simple code:

```
vector<vector<KeyPoint> > dbKeypoints;
vector<Mat> dbDescriptors;
vector<Mat> objects;   

/*
  load Descriptors from images (with OrbDescriptorExtractor())
*/

FlannBasedMatcher matcher;

matcher.add(dbDescriptors); 
matcher.train() //> Crash!
```

If I use `SurfDescriptorExtractor()` it works well.

How can I solve this?

OpenCV says:

```
OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats (type=0
) in unknown function, file D:\Value\Personal\Parthenope\OpenCV\modules\flann\sr
c\miniflann.cpp, line 299
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bug. It will be fixed soon.

http://answers.opencv.org/question/503/how-to-use-the-lshindexparams/

Answer (score 34):

Flann needs the descriptors to be of type CV_32F so you need to convert them! [find_object/example/main.cpp](http://find-object.googlecode.com/svn-history/r55/trunk/find_object/example/main.cpp):

```
if(dbDescriptors.type()!=CV_32F) {
    dbDescriptors.convertTo(dbDescriptors, CV_32F);
}
```

may work ;-)

Comment: If somebody reaches this question but uses the OpenCV for Java, it might be CvType.CV_32F instead of CV_32F. This is due the structure that the OpenCV project decided to do the migration of code from C/C++.

Comment: is FLANNMatcher<L2> will be faster than BFMatcher<NORM_HAMMING> if I convert descriptors?

Comment: I have opened another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43830849/opencv-use-flann-with-orb-descriptors-to-match-features) to ask about an error obtained with this supposed fix.

Answer (score 7):

When using ORB you should construct your matcher like so:

```
FlannBasedMatcher matcher(new cv::flann::LshIndexParams(5, 24, 2));
```

I've also seen [this constructor suggested](http://answers.opencv.org/question/503/how-to-use-the-lshindexparams/):

```
FlannBasedMatcher matcher(new flann::LshIndexParams(20,10,2));
```

Answer (score 5):

**Binary-string descriptors** - ORB, BRIEF, BRISK, FREAK, AKAZE etc.

**Floating-point descriptors** - SIFT, SURF, GLOH etc.

---

Feature matching of binary descriptors can be efficiently done by comparing their **Hamming distance** as opposed to **Euclidean distance** used for floating-point descriptors.

For comparing binary descriptors in OpenCV, use **FLANN + LSH index** or **Brute Force + Hamming distance**.

http://answers.opencv.org/question/59996/flann-error-in-opencv-3/

---

By default FlannBasedMatcher works as KDTreeIndex with L2 norm. This is the reason why it works well with SIFT/SURF descriptors and [throws an exception](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/5937) for ORB descriptor.

[Binary features and Locality Sensitive Hashing (LSH)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296394/binary-features-and-locality-sensitive-hashing-lsh)

[Performance comparison between binary and floating-point descriptors](https://cvlab.epfl.ch/research/page-90554-en-html/research-detect-binarydescriptors/)