# OpenCV - Use FLANN with ORB descriptors to match features

Tags: c++, opencv, orb, flann, feature-descriptor

I am using OpenCV 3.2

I am trying to use FLANN to match features descriptors in a faster way than brute force.

```
// Ratio to the second neighbor to consider a good match.
#define RATIO    0.75

void matchFeatures(const cv::Mat &query, const cv::Mat &target,
                   std::vector<cv::DMatch> &goodMatches) {
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::DMatch>> matches;
    cv::Ptr<cv::FlannBasedMatcher> matcher = cv::FlannBasedMatcher::create();
    // Find 2 best matches for each descriptor to make later the second neighbor test.
    matcher->knnMatch(query, target, matches, 2);
    // Second neighbor ratio test.
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < matches.size(); ++i) {
        if (matches[i][0].distance < matches[i][1].distance * RATIO)
            goodMatches.push_back(matches[i][0]);
    }
}
```

This code is working me with SURF and SIFT descriptors, but not with ORB.

```
OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats (type=0) in buildIndex
```

As it's said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565255/opencv-flann-with-orb-descriptors), FLANN needs the descriptors to be of type CV_32F so we need to convert them.

```
if (query.type() != CV_32F) query.convertTo(query, CV_32F);
if (target.type() != CV_32F) target.convertTo(target, CV_32F);
```

However, this supposed fix is returning me another error in `convertTo` function.

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!fixedType() || ((Mat*)obj)->type() == mtype) in create
```

This assertion is in `opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp` file, line 2277.

What's happening?

---

*Code to replicate issue.*

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // Read both images.
    cv::Mat image1 = cv::imread(argv[1], cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    if (image1.empty()) {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't read image in " << argv[1] << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cv::Mat image2 = cv::imread(argv[2], cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    if (image2.empty()) {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't read image in " << argv[2] << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    // Detect the keyPoints and compute its descriptors using ORB Detector.
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keyPoints1, keyPoints2;
    cv::Mat descriptors1, descriptors2;
    cv::Ptr<cv::ORB> detector = cv::ORB::create();
    detector->detectAndCompute(image1, cv::Mat(), keyPoints1, descriptors1);
    detector->detectAndCompute(image2, cv::Mat(), keyPoints2, descriptors2);
    // Match features.
    std::vector<cv::DMatch> matches;
    matchFeatures(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);
    // Draw matches.
    cv::Mat image_matches;
    cv::drawMatches(image1, keyPoints1, image2, keyPoints2, matches, image_matches);
    cv::imshow("Matches", image_matches);
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Did you adjust the FLANN parameters?

Taken from http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html

> While using ORB, you can pass the following. The commented values are recommended as per the docs, but it didn’t provide required results in some cases. Other values worked fine.:
>
> index_params= dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_LSH,
>                      table_number = 6, # 12
>                      key_size = 12,     # 20
>                      multi_probe_level = 1) #2

Probably you can convert that to C++ api?

According to the comment, the C++ way is:

```
cv::FlannBasedMatcher matcher = cv::FlannBasedMatcher(cv::makePtr<cv::flann::LshIndexParams>(12, 20, 2));
```

Comment: Really worked. The call was `cv::FlannBasedMatcher matcher = cv::FlannBasedMatcher(cv::makePtr<cv::flann::LshIndexParams>(12, 20, 2));`

Comment: As an addition, not all the matches have a correspondence using ORB and FLANN (maybe with other descriptors this also happens, but not for now). Then, in the second neighbor ratio test, I have added a security condition `if (matches[i].size() >= 2)`.

Comment: It is probably worth mentioning that `FLANN_INDEX_LSH = 6`.

Comment: There is also a comment about `multi_probe_level` that it is "number of levels to use in multi-probe (0 for standard LSH)", so it might be better to use `multi_probe_level=0`.

Answer (score 12):

**Binary-string descriptors:** ORB, BRIEF, BRISK, FREAK, AKAZE, etc.

**Floating-point descriptors:** SIFT, SURF, GLOH, etc.

---

Feature matching of binary descriptors can be efficiently done by comparing their **Hamming distance** as opposed to **Euclidean distance** used for floating-point descriptors.

For comparing binary descriptors in OpenCV, use **FLANN + LSH index** or **Brute Force + Hamming distance**.

http://answers.opencv.org/question/59996/flann-error-in-opencv-3/

By default, `FlannBasedMatcher` works as `KDTreeIndex` with L2 norm. This is the reason why it works well with SIFT/SURF descriptors and [throws an exception](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/5937) for ORB descriptor.

[Binary features and Locality Sensitive Hashing (LSH)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296394/binary-features-and-locality-sensitive-hashing-lsh)

[Performance comparison between binary and floating-point descriptors](https://www.epfl.ch/labs/cvlab/research/descriptors-and-keypoints/research-detect-binarydescriptors/)

Comment: Thanks! I have been searching up and down to come down to this post. The opencv error messages are not very clear

Comment: Could you please update the last link (Performance comparison between ...)? It's broken. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @Milan Link updated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a bug in the OpenCV3 version: [FLANN error in OpenCV 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694490/flann-error-in-opencv-3)

You need to convert your descriptors to a 'CV_32F'.