# Custom distance with FLANN in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, flann

Is there a way to define our own distance for FLANN tool in OpenCV. This question has been asked here but remains not answered for more than 6 years.

Comment: You mean not L1, L2, or Linfinity distance?

Comment: There are a few different algorithms/metrics implemented, but probably you can't easily provide your own. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43830849/opencv-use-flann-with-orb-descriptors-to-match-features/43835993#43835993 for LSH which can be used for binary features' distances.

Comment: @wcochran Yes. None of these. For my distance I compute N chi squared distances between feature A and circular shifted feature B (shifted N times). The minimal distance is returned.

Comment: You can probably implement that yourself. OpenCV is open source.

Comment: @Micka. Yes if I had more time.